# How to include Voltage code in 4 digit 7 segment dislay

Tags: arduino-uno

As a continuation of my question. Here's the code for controlling the 4 digit 7 segment display:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int c = 4;
int d = 5;
int e = 6;
int f = 7;
int g = 8;
int p = 9;

int d4 = 10;
int d3 = 11;
int d2 = 12;
int d1 = 13;

void setup()
{
  //set all the pins of the LED display as output
  pinMode(d1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(d2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(d3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(d4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(c, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(d, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(e, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(f, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(g, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(p, OUTPUT);

}
/***************************************/ 
void loop()

{
  //The 7-segment LED display is a common-cathode one. So also use digitalWrite to  set d1 as high and the LED will go out
  digitalWrite(d1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d4, HIGH);

  switch(x)
  {
    case 0: 
    digitalWrite(d1, LOW);//Light d1 up 
    break;
    case 1: 
    digitalWrite(d2, LOW); //Light d2 up 
    break;
    case 2: 
    digitalWrite(d3, LOW); //Light d3 up 
    break;
    default: 
    digitalWrite(d4, LOW); //Light d4 up 
    break;
  }
}
//The function is to control the 7-segment LED display to display numbers. Here x is the number to be displayed. It is an integer from 0 to 9 
void pickNumber(int x)
{
  switch(x)
  {
    default: 
    zero(); 
    break;
    case 1: 
    one(); 
    break;
    case 2: 
    two(); 
    break;
    case 3: 
    three(); 
    break;
    case 4: 
    four(); 
    break;
    case 5: 
    five(); 
    break;
    case 6: 
    six(); 
    break;
    case 7: 
    seven(); 
    break;
    case 8: 
    eight(); 
    break;
    case 9: 
    nine(); 
    break;
  }
} 
void clearLEDs() //clear the 7-segment display screen
{
  digitalWrite(a, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b, LOW);
  digitalWrite(c, LOW);
  digitalWrite(d, LOW);
  digitalWrite(e, LOW);
  digitalWrite(f, LOW);
  digitalWrite(g, LOW);
  digitalWrite(p, LOW);
}

void zero() //the 7-segment led display 0
{
  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(g, LOW);
}

void one() //the 7-segment led display 1
{
  digitalWrite(a, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, LOW);
  digitalWrite(e, LOW);
  digitalWrite(f, LOW);
  digitalWrite(g, LOW);
}

void two() //the 7-segment led display 2
{
  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(c, LOW);
  digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(f, LOW);
  digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
}

void three() //the 7-segment led display 3
{
  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(e, LOW);
  digitalWrite(f, LOW);
  digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
}

void four() //the 7-segment led display 4
{
  digitalWrite(a, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, LOW);
  digitalWrite(e, LOW);
  digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
}

void five() //the 7-segment led display 5
{
  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(b, LOW);
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(e, LOW);
  digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
}

void six() //the 7-segment led display 6
{
  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(b, LOW);
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
}

void seven() //the 7-segment led display 7
{
  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, LOW);
  digitalWrite(e, LOW);
  digitalWrite(f, LOW);
  digitalWrite(g, LOW);
}

void eight() //the 7-segment led display 8
{
  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
}

void nine() //the 7-segment led display 9
{
  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(e, LOW);
  digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
```

My problem is how to include the voltage code here? Here's the code for voltage code:

```
    /*
* Display5vOrless sketch
* prints the voltage on analog pin to the serial port
* Warning - do not connect more than 5 volts directly to an Arduino pin.
*/

const float referenceVolts = 5.0; // the default reference on a 5-volt board
const int batteryPin = 0; // battery is connected to analog pin 0

void setup() 
{
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
 int val = analogRead(batteryPin); // read the value from the sensor 
 float volts = (val / 1023.0) * referenceVolts; // calculate the ratio
 Serial.println(volts); // print the value in volts
 delay(500);
 }
```

Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you want to merge them before they are working? Check them first then try to merge them yourself. How would you go about that? Describe your reasoning. Then and only then ask for help.

Comment: Isn't there a library for this, im thinking there is some steps that you need to cover before it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can display single digits what happen when you want to display double or triple digits. You need a code that can handle that. You need to cut up volts an iterare over it. Anyway create a class that takes volt and return it on the display. That's what you you need to do to merge that code. Are you up for that? Or are you gonna find a library that can handle that?